# click event not firing on newly created list item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two lists and when you click on the second list the first list removes the first item and add to the second list but when I click on the newly created list item it doesn't fire why is that. [jsFiddle demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/g84K9/)

```
$('#SearchList li a').bind("click", function () {
    var $this = $(this).unwrap('<a href="#"></a>').remove().text();

    var $that = $('#Search li:first').remove().text();

    $('<li>' + $this + '</li>').insertBefore('#Search li:first')

    $('#SearchList').append('<li><a href="#">' + $that + '</a></li>');
});

<ul id="Search">
    <li>Electronics</li>
    <li>Image</li>
</ul>

<ul id="SearchList">                        
    <li><a href="#">Interests</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clothing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pharmacy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home & Garden</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.bind()` only affects elements already in the DOM, you want to use `.delegate()` or `.on()` (if you are using jQuery 1.7+):

```
$('#SearchList').on("click", " li a", function () {
    var $this = $(this).unwrap('<a href="#"></a>').remove().text();

    var $that = $('#Search li:first').remove().text();

    $('<li>' + $this + '</li>').insertBefore('#Search li:first')

    $('#SearchList').append('<li><a href="#">' + $that + '</a></li>');
});
```

Note: `.live()` has been depreciated as of jQuery 1.7, so it's a good idea to either use `.on()` or `.delegate()`.

Here is a jsfiddle of the above solution (using jQuery 1.7): http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/pgwdv/

Some documentation links:

- `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on
- `.delegate()`: http://api.jquery.com/delegate

Comment: And this should be plussed because I believe .on() is the current standard. .live() is just what I'm used to and .live() supersedes .delegate(), which I believe supersedes .bind()... ever evolving jquery.

Comment: @KaiQing `$('#element_id').live('click', function () {...})` is basically `$(document).delegate('#element_id', 'click', function () {...});` Delegate gives you the ability to specify a different parent object than `document` so there isn't so much bubbling up to `document` going-on.

Comment: My code is pretty simple how would you write out what I've done, thanks for you're help that worked

Comment: I tried to use wrap('<a href="#"></a>') for $that but it doesn't work how do you use wrap in this case

Comment: @KDM If you check-out my jsfiddle or even the code above, it should paste directly into your page (if you have jQuery 1.7 included, which is a good idea anyways). If you are using an older version of jQuery then all that needs to change is: `$('#SearchList li a').bind("click", function () {` changes to: `$('#SearchList').delegate("li a", "click", function () {`. I updated your jsfiddle here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/g84K9/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should try using .live instead of .bind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to keep click (and other) handlers active for dynamically added content.

Instead of

```
$('#SearchList li a').bind("click", function () {
```

Use

```
$('#SearchList li a').live("click", function () {
```